# Overachieving badge notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed

So I'm happy to add another bronze badge to my collection for [this stupendously awesome question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68411/applying-for-a-canadian-eta-after-previous-visits-without-one)...  but not quite *this* happy:

[image]

They don't all fit in the screenshot, but at time of writing I have 26 (twenty-six) identical notifications. (o_O;

Everything else seems to work fine, including a single notification for another "Popular Question" badge.

Comment: [Reported on meta.SE, status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283748)

Answer (score 6):

As @Jan mentioned, this was a systemwide bug in the whole SE network, and was mentioned on [Meta SE today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283760/321647):

> We had a problem with badges failing to
>   award last night, so I added some extra logging to capture more info
>   when it stumbled. In the process I accidentally broke something such
>   that it appeared to work, but really didn't actually do anything.
>   Deploying the fix now. Sorry folks.

It has since been fixed.